# Adding HTML - Badges with Javascript

Tags: javascript

i wanted to add content to a customers website, depending on what css class he declares in the cms backend. So for example if he types in "Berlin", there should appear an HTML Element with the name of the city. If he types "Berlin Munich", two elements should appear and so on.

Here is my code so far:

```
var course = document.querySelector(".course");
var courseClass = course.className;
var locations = [
"Berlin", "Munich", "London"
];

function addLocations () {
    for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        if (courseClass.includes(locations[i])) {
            course.innerHTML = `<h1>${locations[i]}</h1>`
        }
    }
}

addLocations();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ce_text course cham block">
<h2>Tierheilpraktiker</h2>
<p><strong>Komplettausbildung<br></strong><br>
beinhaltet Veterinärmedizinische Grundlagen / klassische Homöopathie nach
Hahnemann / Tierakupunktur Komplettausbildung nach TCM /
Phytotherapieausbildung (als Option mit Ausbildung Touch for Health
einzigartig in dieser Kombination)</p>
</div>
```

Maybe someone can help me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
var courses = document.getElementsByClassName("course");
var locations = ["Berlin", "Munich", "London"];
for(var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
  var list = courses[i].className.split(" ");
  for(var j = 0; j < locations.length; j++) {
    if (list.includes(locations[j])) {
        courses[i].innerHTML = courses[i].innerHTML + " " + locations[j];
    }
   }
}
```

HTML would look like this

```
<ul>
  <li class="course Berlin Munich"></li>
  <li class="course Munich"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
unfortunately only one element appears  although i declare multiple classes...

Comment: Ah ok did not know about this use case. Edited the code. Should work now.

Comment: Hey there! I think there i still a bug. If i run the code, i just get "undefined" and nothing happens in the frontend...

Comment: Seems to be a bug that has nothing to do with the code. Because in this standalone project it works https://jsfiddle.net/43owax8v/

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe split the className to make your code work :

```
var courseClass = course.className.split(" ");
```